# On $i.o.P/poly$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity

> 1. Is $NEXP^{NP}\not\subseteq i.o.P/poly$?
> 2. Is there any consequence if $NP$ or $PP$ is in $i.o.P/poly$?

Showing $NEXP^{NP}\not\subseteq P/poly$ needs Karp-Lipton.

<s>What is the best $i.o.P/poly$ lower bound result we know</s>? As of this writing this is $EXP^{\Sigma_2P}\not\subseteq i.o.P/poly$.

Comment: Doesn't EXPSPACE contain this function https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/22183/4896, whose intersection with $\{0,1\}^n$ has circuit complexity $2^{n/2}$ for *every* $n$?

Comment: My understanding is a class could not be in $P/poly$ but could be in $i.o.P/poly$ (actually I was interested $NEXP^{NP}$ and $EXP^{PP}$).

Comment: You should really ask the questions you are interested in then.

Comment: For your modified question: isn't the exponential time hierarchy contained in EXP$^{PP}$ by a scaled up version of Toda's theorem? And wouldn't that answer your question for the same reason that I pointed out above?

Comment: Wait, what is the "standard proof" that NEXP^NP is not in P/poly? It is not known if PH collapses assuming NP is in io-P/poly... so I don't see how you get an a.e. lower bound easily, since the usual proof uses Karp-Lipton. See for example Fortnow and Santhanam's "Robust Simulations and Significant Separations" for a discussion. You can get EXP^(Sigma2 P) not in io-P/poly, because that can be proved with a direct diagonalization on each input length.

Comment: @RyanWilliams That is correct there is no Karp-Lipton in that case. Could you elaborate on the $EXP^{\Sigma_2^P}$ lower bound?

Comment: See for example Miltersen Vinodchandran and Watanabe 99

Comment: EXP$^{\Sigma_2^P}$ contains the language in the answer I linked in my first comment: see Emil's comments under the answer. That language is designed to have exponential circuit complexity for all $n$. If EXP$^{PP}$ indeed contains the exponential hierarchy, then it will contain EXP$^{\Sigma_2^P}$, and the same language.